# Python Record Linkage Multiple Cores

Tags: python, duplicates, record-linkage

Does anyone have experience using the Record Linkage Toolkit with extremely large datasets?  I have a few questions.  Utlimately, I need to deploy it to an EC2 instance, but for now, I'm trying to figure out how to take advantage of parallel processing - I'll want to do the same on EC2.

When specifying the number of cores (njobs), the code actually runs significantly SLOWER than if I don't specify multiple cores.

```
compare_dupes = rl.Compare(n_jobs=12)
```

Related to this - I am working on a record set with 12 million customer records that need to be deduped.  Currently I'm blocking on first name, last name, and zip code.

However, the number of potential record pairs index is still so large that it causes memory failures.   I have tried Dask - no luck.  I'm not sure what else to try.  Anyone have suggestions?  My code looks like this:

```
# this section creates a huge multi-index, which causes memory failures
dupe_indexer = rl.Index()
dupe_indexer.block(['first_name_clean','last_name_clean','zip_clean'])
dupe_candidate_links = dupe_indexer.index(df_c)


# I can put n_jobs=12 (the number of cores) in the Compare function below, 
# but for some reason it actually performs worse

compare_dupes = rl.Compare()
compare_dupes.string('first_name_clean','first_name_clean', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85, label='first_name_cl')
compare_dupes.string('last_name_clean','last_name_clean', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85, label='last_name_cl')
compare_dupes.string('email', 'email', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.90, label='email_cl')
compare_dupes.string('address_clean','address_clean', method='damerau_levenshtein', threshold=0.6, label='address_cl')

compare_dupes.string('zip_clean','zip_clean', method='jarowinkler',threshold=0.90, label='zip_cl'
dupe_features = compare_dupes.compute(dupe_candidate_links, df_c).reset_index()
```

I have also tried the "index_split" method:

```
 s = rl.index_split(dupe_candidate_links, 100)
 for chunk in s:
```

which works for reasonably size data sets < 2 million, but when the size of the dataset gets beyond that 5, 8, 10, 15, 20 million - even the index can't fit into memory.

Thanks for any support!

Comment: do you solve your problem, i am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer mostly on memory usage problem.

The documentation suggests to go for splitting one of the datasets into smaller subsets with large files.

See [indexing-with-large-files](https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/performance.html?highlight=large%20files#indexing-with-large-files)

Here is slightly improved version of the documentation

```
import recordlinkage
import numpy

indexer = recordlinkage.Index
indexer.full()

for dfB_subset in numpy.array_split(dfB, 100):

    # a subset of record pairs
    pairs_subset = indexer.index(dfA, dfB_subset)

    # Your analysis on pairs_subset here
    pot_matches = compare_cl.compute(pairs_subset, dfA, dfB_subset)
```

My use case was with full index and input size of approx 10k where I had to split one set into approx 100 subsets. With 1M records you might need to put number of subsets to some extreme value or might even need to split both arrays. However, you are doing some blocking which I have not done and that might impact the number of pairs generated significantly.

Ultimately, I am not sure that number of subsets impacts the performance. The assumption is: the amount of work to do the comparison remains the same(?).

Regarding the performance, I think you should not equal the cores. I see approx 50% improvement in performance when specifying n_jobs = 6 on an 8 core machine.

Note: I am in no way an expert in python.

Answer (score -1):

```
indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
#Create indexing object
indexer = rl.SortedNeighbourhoodIndex(on='X')
# Create pandas MultiIndex containing candidate links
candidate_links = indexer.index(A, B)


%%time
comp = recordlinkage.Compare()
comp.string('X', 'X', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.60)
mymatchestwonew = comp.compute(candidate_links, A, B)
```